# Scheduled jobs in Openshift. Other than cron service

Tags: heroku, cron, openshift

I want to add scheduled jobs in Openshift, which would be getting added dynamically to my application. I had tried the cron service on Openshift, but it stops after certain amount of time. I want to add a service similar to Iron workers or heroku workers, but these services seem to be costly. Also is it possible to implement such a service on our own in Openshift?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm guessing your Cron service is stopping when your application idles. Idling occurs when your app doesn't receive web traffic for 24 hours. Just upgrade to the Bronze plan to remove idling (it's free).

Second off, you can add IronWorker as an Add-on Service through the OpenShift Marketplace: https://hub.openshift.com/addons/10-ironworker

If you're using Ruby you could also just run Resque with Redque Scheduler along with the downloadable Redis cartridge:

- Resque/Resque Scheduler: https://github.com/resque
- Redis: https://hub.openshift.com/addons/34-redis